# convert preload img to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, preloading

```
$('<img />')
   .attr('src', val)
   .attr('width', "400")
   .load(function(){
      $('.showdata').append( $(this) );
   }
);
```

This works perfectly for images, how would this convert 1:1 to iframes?
Here quick jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ET8Gw/

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer on what you're trying to achieve? What problem are you having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Image objects, IFrames will not load until they are part of the DOM.

To get around this you can hide the element, add it to the DOM, and when the load event fires show it:

```
var val = "http://dumb.com/";
 $('<iframe />')
            .hide()
            .attr('src', val)
            .attr('width', "500")
            .load(function(){
                $(this).show();
            })
            .appendTo(".showdata");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ET8Gw/1/

Comment: @Writecoder, if that answer solves your problem, please consider choosing it as the solution to your question by clicking the green checkmark to the left

Answer (score 2):

```
var val = "http://inapcache.boston.com/universal/site_graphics/blogs/bigpicture/texas_drought_fires/bp1.jpg";
$('<iframe/>')
    .attr('src', val)
    .attr('width', "500")
    .appendTo($('.showdata'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ET8Gw/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$("<iframe></iframe>")
    .css("display":"none")
    .attr('src', val)
    .load( 
        function(){
            $(this).show();
        })
    .appendTo(".showData");
```

It will not work cross domain.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working doing this

```
var val = "http://inapcache.boston.com/universal/site_graphics/blogs/bigpicture/texas_drought_fires/bp1.jpg";

$('.showdata').append('<iframe src="' + val + '" width="400" height="200"><\/iframe>');
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ET8Gw/22/