# Convert image calling JQuery to iFrame call

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I just purchased this template: http://ferdiaobrien.com/template/

It does everything I need bar one small problem. Can any jQuery experts tell me how I might be able to change the function that calls the larger images on the homepage (and other pages that do the same thing), so that instead it calls an iFrame? That way I can display whatever I like, not just images.

I am fairly sure that this is the file that handles it all, but javascript is all Greek to me: http://ferdiaobrien.com/template/js/dynamicpage.js

So to make it totally plain for everyone who, unlike me, knows what they are doing with jQuery, I want to be able to make a list like this:

```
<ul class="thumbs">
    <li><a href="frames/frame1.php"><img src="images/photo/tfile_small_1_1.jpg" alt="" title=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

instead of the current format of this, which I have copied and pasted from the template:

```
<ul class="thumbs">
    <li><a href="images/photo/tfile_gall_1_1.jpg"><img src="images/photo/tfile_small_1_1.jpg" alt="" title=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

and have it display the contents of frame1.php, rather than tfile_gall_1_1.jpg, and so on.

I think this is the function to load the first image:

```
initGallery =
    function(){
        var $gal = $('#gallery'),
            img_link = $gal.find('.thumbs li:first-child').children('a').attr("href");

        $gal.find('.thumbs li:first-child').addClass("current").find('img').fadeTo('500', 0);

        $loading.show();

        _img=$('<img class="big_img">')
        _img.css({left:"100px", top:"30px", opacity:0}).load(
            function(){
                $loading.hide();
                $gal.prepend(this);
                $(this).animate({left:"17px", top:0, opacity:1}, 500);
            })
            .attr({src:img_link});

        $gal.children('.gallery_nav').tinycarousel({ axis: 'y'});

        $gal.find("ul.thumbs li").each(
            function(){
                var thumbUrl = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
                $(this).children().css({'background' : 'url(' + thumbUrl + ') no-repeat right top'});
            }
        );

        $gal.hover(
            function(){
                $('.gallery_nav', this).stop().animate({right:0}, 'fast')
            },
            function(){
                $('.gallery_nav', this).stop().animate({right:"-164px"}, 'fast')
            }
        );
    };
```

And this is the one for subsequent images:

```
$mainContent.delegate("#gallery .thumbs a", "click", function(){

    if($(this).parent().is(".current")){
        return false
    }
    else {
    $(this).parent().addClass("current").find("img").css({opacity:0}).parent().parent().siblings(".current").removeClass("current").find("img").css({opacity:1});
        var img_link = $(this).attr("href");
        var $gal = $('#gallery');
        $loading.show();
        $gal.children('.big_img').animate({left:"-40px", top:"40px", opacity:0}, 500 , function(){
            $(this).remove()
        });

        _img=$('<img class="big_img">')
        _img.css({left:"100px", top:"30px", opacity:0}).load(
            function(){
                $loading.hide();
                $gal.prepend(this);
                $(this).animate({left:"17px", top:0, opacity:1}, 500);
            })
            .attr({src:img_link});

            return false;
        }
    });
```

But when I change

```
_img=$('<img class="big_img">')
```

to

```
_img=$('<iframe class="big_img"></iframe>')
```

it refuses to generate the HTML. It seems to have something to do with this: [convert preload img to iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390666/convert-preload-img-to-iframe?rq=1)
but I just can't get my head around it.

Thanks in advance

**Update:**
So I have tracked the problem down to here: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.ie/2010/02/dynamically-create-iframe-with-jquery.html

I have tried to add the append() function to the code, but it seems to enter an infinite loop of generating the iframe, and then generating it again.

Comment: The JS file if only about behavior and not about html generation. Try to search where the <ul> element is generated in the template files

Comment: Hi there, I know where that is, the ul detailed above is a copy and paste. The problem is when I enter anything that isn't an image, the loading image never disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the solution was to comment out the two excerpts that control the image (listed in question) and then add the following to a new file:

```
function loadIframe(iframeName, url) {
    var $iframe = $('#' + iframeName);
    if ($iframe.length) {
        $iframe.attr('src', url);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

set up an initial iframe such as:

```
<iframe src="" width="630" height="420" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen name="ifrm" id="ifrm"></iframe>
```

and then in the menu add onClicks like so:

```
<ul class="thumbs">
    <li><a href="" onClick="return loadIframe('ifrm', this.href);"><img src="img/photo/" alt="" title=""></a></li>
```